Android: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0
Error coming
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions

FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find :unspecified:.
     Required by:
         project :app > id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
    at 
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
Required by:
    project :app
Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.2.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
  - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
Required by:
    project :app
Cause 3: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
  - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
Required by:
    project :app
Cause 4: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
  - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
Required by:
    project :app
Cause 5: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find :unspecified:.
Required by:
    project :app > id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0

==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/chaos/view/pinview/1.4.2/pinview-1.4.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/qrcodereaderview/2.0.3/qrcodereaderview-2.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/plattysoft/leonids/LeonidsLib/1.3.2/LeonidsLib-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find :unspecified:.
     Required by:
         project :app > id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.InputFingerprinter$InputFileFingerprintingException: Cannot fingerprint input file property 'externalLibNativeLibs': Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter$InputCollectingVisitor.visitInputFileProperty(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep$1.visitInputFileProperty(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitRegularInputs(TaskExecution.java:322)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$fingerprintPrimaryInputs$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter.fingerprintInputProperties(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.fingerprintPrimaryInputs(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.InputFingerprinter$InputFileFingerprintingException: Cannot fingerprint input file property 'externalLibNativeLibs': Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.mapFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1531)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$3800(DefaultConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$DefaultResolutionHost.mapFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:2183)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$DefaultResolutionHost.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:2188)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1499)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getFiles(AbstractFileCollection.java:129)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.FilteredFileCollection.iterator(FilteredFileCollection.java:79)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(ImmutableSet.java:262)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$1.visitCollection(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:247)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitContents(AbstractFileCollection.java:380)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.lambda$calculateFinalizedValue$0(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:411)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.calculateFinalizedValue(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:280)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:333)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.PropertyFileCollection.visitChildren(PropertyFileCollection.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter$InputCollectingVisitor.visitInputFileProperty(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:131)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
  - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/ss/bannerslider/bannerslider/2.0.0/bannerslider-2.0.0.pom
Required by:
    project :app

==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 12s
18 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 2 up-to-date



build.gradle file
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


build.gradle(app) file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.1.9"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.marchinram:RxGallery:0.6.5'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.0'
}
googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true



Most of the time these errors are from internet connections,
but in this situation, many of your libs were from Bintray(shut down and no longer available) and deprecated or from repo.spring.io which has private access.
you should remove and replace them with some other libs.
for some libs, you can use another version:
Pinview:
repositories {
    maven {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'io.github.chaosleung:pinview:1.4.4'
}

QRCodeReaderView:
implementation 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.2'

